# extract servers' blocks from Nginx conf

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression, nginx

I have the following conf file for nginx:

```
user       www www;  ## Default: nobody
...

events {
  worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}

http {
  include    conf/mime.types;
  ...

  server { # php/fastcgi
    listen       80;
    server_name  domain1.com www.domain1.com;
    access_log   logs/domain1.access.log  main;
    root         html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:1025;
    }
  }

  server { # simple reverse-proxy
    listen       80;
    server_name  domain2.com www.domain2.com;
    access_log   logs/domain2.access.log  main;

    # serve static files
    location ~ ^/(images|javascript|js|css|flash|media|static)/  {
      root    /var/www/virtual/big.server.com/htdocs;
      expires 30d;
    }

    # pass requests for dynamic content to rails/turbogears/zope, et al
    location / {
      proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
  }
}
```

This is a `foo` example that I found on www.nginx.com.

The goal is to extract all the servers' blocks for various treatments. In this particular case, there are two servers' blocks that I am interested in.

Because I work on very limited environments, I can only use sed/grep/awk/unix systems commands. No python, no pearl, ...

The problem with that kind of configuration files is that it is *maybe possible* that the `server` block itself contains some sub-blocks (i.e `server { ... directive { ... }}`). Considering that, it is impossible to simply use `grep -oP "server {.*?}"`.

Can `grep` do the job? I've tried many different regex but didn't find the good one. For now, I worked with the above file without backslash (i.e `cat $FILE | tr -d "\n"`). I've tried things like `grep -oP "server\s{1,}{.*?({.*?}){0,}}"` but it does not fit my needs...

The reason I want to use `grep` is that I think that `awk` is not very readable afterward, and to maintain the code should be easier with `grep` - but I could make an exception if it is way easier with `awk`!

Thanks :)

**EDIT:**

Output should looks like:

```
"server { # php/fastcgi
  listen       80;
  server_name  domain1.com www.domain1.com;
  access_log   logs/domain1.access.log  main;
  root         html;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:1025;
  }
}",
"server { # simple reverse-proxy
  listen       80;
  server_name  domain2.com www.domain2.com;
  access_log   logs/domain2.access.log  main;

  # serve static files
  location ~ ^/(images|javascript|js|css|flash|media|static)/  {
    root    /var/www/virtual/big.server.com/htdocs;
    expires 30d;
  }

  # pass requests for dynamic content to rails/turbogears/zope, et al
  location / {
    proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8080;
  }
}"
```

Something that I can treat using commands like `echo $OUTPUT | tr -d ... | grep -v ...`. If possible, I want to have each server block extracted on a single line to loop on the result!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for something like:

```
$ awk '/server *{/{c=1; print;next} c&&/{/{c++} c&&/}/{c--} c' file
  server { # php/fastcgi
    listen       80;
    server_name  domain1.com www.domain1.com;
    access_log   logs/domain1.access.log  main;
    root         html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:1025;
    }
  }

  server { # simple reverse-proxy
    listen       80;
    server_name  domain2.com www.domain2.com;
    access_log   logs/domain2.access.log  main;

    # serve static files
    location ~ ^/(images|javascript|js|css|flash|media|static)/  {
      root    /var/www/virtual/big.server.com/htdocs;
      expires 30d;
    }

    # pass requests for dynamic content to rails/turbogears/zope, et al
    location / {
      proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
  }
```

#### Explanation

- `/server *{/{c=1; print; next;}` : if this line matches `server`, 0 or more spaces and then a `{`, set the variable `c` to 1. So, `c` will be 1 each time we find a new `server{` block. Then `print` the line and skip to the `next` one.
- `c&&/{/{c++}` : if the `c` is defined and not 0, and this line matches a `{`, increment `c` by 1 (`c++`). This could have been written as `if(c && /{/){ c=c+1}`. So, the value of `c` will increase for each nested `{` block found.
- `c&&/}/{c--}` : if `c` is defined and not 0, and this line matches a `}`, decrement `c` by 1. This could have been written as `if(c && /}/){c=c-1}`. This ensures that the value of `c` goes down as each nested `{}` block is closed.
- `c` : this is an `awk` trick. The default action when something evaluates to true in `awk` is to print the current line. Here, it will print if `c` is defined and not 0 (true). Because of the commands above which increment and decrement `c` depending on whether we're in a `server` block, this will result in printing only the lines you're after.

Comment: It is not working for me; I've tested with both original file and with a `file` where I did a copy-n-paste of the content given in this post!

Comment: @ColinLeverger ah, I think the `\s` is a GNUism. Try the updated answer.

Comment: Just be careful of commented out lines that may cause incorrect behaviour...

Comment: @StephenHarris you mean things like `# foo { bar`? I guess the OP could always just pass the file through `grep -v #` or something.

Comment: @terdon Thank you, it is now working perfectly well :) (`awk` is still a little hard to read but it is nice!). Do you think that `grep` could do the job...?

Comment: @ColinLeverger no, `grep` is not the right tool here. It's designed for printing lines matching specific patterns. Matching multiline patterns is possible with GNU grep using the `-Z` flag to slurp the entire file, but here you also need to keep track of nested brackets so no, it won't work.

Comment: Hi @terdon, could you explain more this awk command, so I can adapt it for a new need I have? I am still working with nginx conf files and I need to extract `location ~ \.php$ { ... }` blocks.

Comment: @ColinLeverger see updated answer. To get the `location ~ \.php$ { }` block in your example, you could just change the `/server *{/` to `/location.*php\$/`.

Comment: @ColinLeverger by the way, if the size of the blocks is always the same, always `location ~ .php$ {`,one line, and the closing `}`, you *can* actually use `grep`: `grep -A2 'location.*php\$' file`. It just won't work if the size of the block is variable.

Comment: @terdon I have the same problematic here: blocs with variable size and optional `{...}` inside of them. Using `awk '/location.*php\$ *{/{c=1} c&&/{/{c++} c&&/}/{c--} c'` doesn't seems to work exactly the same in this case, and I don't know why - it definitely should. I am investigating at the moment.

Comment: @ColinLeverger OK, but please don't do this in comments. Either post a new question, showing your input file and the command you're trying which fails or come into [/dev/chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat). That command works as expected on your example.